# How can I combine two excel columns during import to a database?

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net, import-from-excel

I am trying to combine a date and time columns in excel and map it to one column in a database using sqlbulkcopy. I am getting an error:

> Date][time does not match any column mapping

See my sample code below. Any ideas on how to accomplish this without copying it to a Datatable?

```
Dim sSourceConstr As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", sPath)

Dim sDestConstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SolCards").ConnectionString
Dim sSourceConnection As New OleDbConnection(sSourceConstr)
Using sSourceConnection
    Dim sql As String = String.Format("Select [Customer Cod],[Customer],[PAN],[Vehicle],[Date],[Station],[Driver],[Authorized],[Product]" &
                                          ", [Pump], [Tran No], [Odo], [Metric], [UPrice], [Qty], [Amount], [TimeFormat] FROM [{0}$]", "trans")
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, sSourceConnection)

    sSourceConnection.Open()
    Using dr As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Using bulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(sDestConstr)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "FuelInformation"
            'column mapping               

          bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[Date] [Time]", "DatePurchased")

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: `Select [Customer Cod]+' '+[Customer]` - this is to combine columns

Comment: Then i get this error "The provider could not determine the DateTime value" @zackraiyan

Comment: Is there any column containing date and time ??

Comment: hey wait! `bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[Date] [Time]", "DatePurchased")` ...This wouldn't work.You need to declare what [date],[time] is related to

Comment: see my answer..

Comment: I have been trying it like this "Select [Date] + ' ' + [Time] as [DatePurchased] " and using the [DatePurchased] as the new source column for the mapping. But then I get the "Determine the DateTime value".

Comment: @zackraiyan didnt work

Answer (score 1):

The way I got around this was by using excel actual formula of CONCATENATE. You can either put it in your code or in the spreadsheet add a new column and call the value of that cell.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for the error is :

```
 "Select ([date],[time])values(@date,@time)"
   bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("@Date", "DatePurchased")
   bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("@time", "DatePurchased")
```

Comment: I got this error : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '([Date],[Time])values(@Date,@Time)'.

Comment: This is my select statement: "Select [Customer Cod],[Customer],[PAN],[Vehicle],([Date],[Time])values(@Date,@Time),[Station],[Driver],[Authorized],[Product], [Pump], [Tran No], [Odo], [Metric], [UPrice], [Qty], [Amount], [TimeFormat] FROM [{0}$]", "trans")

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using CStr() as below, the issue with combining the two columns was the column header names having keywords as their names.

```
 Dim sSourceConstr As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", sPath)

    Dim sDestConstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SolCards").ConnectionString
    Dim sSourceConnection As New OleDbConnection(sSourceConstr)
    Using sSourceConnection
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT CStr([Date]) + ' ' + CStr([Time]) as [DatePurchased] ,[Customer Cod],[Customer],[PAN],[Vehicle],[Station],[Driver],[Authorized],[Product], [Pump], [Tran No], [Odo], [Metric], [UPrice], [Qty], [Amount], [TimeFormat] FROM [{0}$]", "trans")
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, sSourceConnection)

        sSourceConnection.Open()
        Using dr As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Using bulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(sDestConstr)
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "FuelInformation"
                'column mapping 
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[DatePurchased]", "DatePurchased")

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
            End Using
        End Using

    End Using
```